# Number of syllables per line of The Raven by Edgar Allan Poe

Tags: poetry

After reading some analysis of "The Raven", I've become confused about how syllables are counted. For example, in the second line:

*Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore*

A few sources say there are 15 syllables, and that it ends with half a foot. However, I count 17 syllables, and it doesn't seem to be trochaic octameter unless I count "many a" as 2 syllables (MA-nya) and curious as 2 (CU-rious). Is it correct to do so, or am I missing something?

Comment: This is not sufficient to post as an answer, and the question might be migrated, but I think you've got it right. I'd read it as "manya" and "curyus" to fit the meter.

Comment: Hi Daniel, and welcome! Unfortunately, questions about existing works are off topic as per our [help/on-topic]. This might however well be on topic *if* you can show how it relates to an issue you're facing in your own writing. I have temporarily put your question on hold. If you can [Edit] your question to clarify that, we might well be able to reopen it quickly and you can get the answers you seek. For questions seeking to analyze existing literature, I suggest that you check out our sister site [literature.se]; for linguistic questions, try [english.se] or [linguistics.se]. Enjoy your stay!

Comment: Says Poe in "The Philosophy of Composition":  I pretend to no originality in either the rhythm or metre of the “Raven.” The former is trochaic — the latter is octametre acatalectic, alternating with heptameter catalectic repeated in the refrain of the 5th verse, and terminating with tetrameter catalectic. [...] the feet employed throughout (trochees) consist of a long syllable followed by a short: the 1st line of the stanza consists of 8 of these feet — the 2nd of seven and a half (in effect 2/3) — the 3rd of 8 — the 4th of seven and a half — the 5th the same — the 6th three and a half.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't know about that restriction. I'll post it on the Literature stack exchange, thanks.